# Getting dropdown list selection in secondary thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list and I have a secondary thread starting in which I have to get the selected value of that dropdown list. It's always returning null or empty string. Is there a way to get its value in the secondary string?

Comment: send/give the value before start the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI elements are owned by the UI thread. Never try to access or even modify these, as this is not a tread safe operation. Pass the values of the dropdown the the thread when you create it and use the copied values in the second thread.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(asyncCode);
    myThread.Start(yourParameterObject);
}

static void asyncCode(object parameters)
{
    // Use the parameters passed
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the values to the new thread? I use Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(MyMethod) which receives the method name as a parameter but the method itself must be without parameters. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that addition. However from what I read that enables sending only one parameter (unless maybe they're sent as an array or list. Is that possible?). I found another opption using a lambda expression: Thread t = new Thread ( () => asyncCode (param1, param2) ); static void asyncCode(int param1, string param2) {     // Use the parameters passed }

Comment: @DovMiller: the parameter you can pass is of type object, therefore you can pass any type that derives from object. You can create a class that contains multiple parameters as properties.